# Pasting Cyrillic Commands into Terminal with Vagrant VM

Tags: mysql, vagrant, locale, cyrillic, vagrant-provision

I am having issues pasting commands that include Cyrillic into Terminal when using Vagrant. Sometimes it works, but with other commands, the pasted command will just get jumbled, with the cursor stuck in the middle, not allowing any further edits - other than hitting enter.

For instance, this command will throw it off. I could do it with our without MySQL running, it will yield the same:

INSERT INTO locations (id, location_name_e, location_name_r, address_lat, address_lon, notes) VALUES (2, 'Leningrad', 'Ленинград', '59.9343', '30.3351')

In Vagrant:

[Plain text command pasted into Vagrant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBQWi.png)

Without Vagrant up, pasting the command will work just fine:

[Plain text command pasted into Terminal without Vagrant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyZUP.png)

It's plain text.
All encodings are enabled in Terminal.
Changing the locale in the Vagrant provisioning didn't seem to help.
With or without MySQL running, pasting produces the same issues.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Philip Gleissner.  It seems possible that some minimum code example of which inserts work and which do not, along with some sample data will be helpful to those looking to provide solutions.

Comment: @Degan, thank you. I added to screenshots. Also, I eliminated more origins of the problem. It's not a MySQL problem and it really isn't the locale - I replicated my standard locale in Vagrant, and it still caused the same issue.